# Trouble getting my phones current location using Google Earth

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am fairly new to android programming and was looking to play around with google earth. I want to be able to find my phones current location using its GPS. I followed some online tutorials and have got the following code.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
        LatLng Uni = new LatLng(53.767735, -0.368377);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(Uni).title("University"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(Uni));

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

    }

}
```

These are my manifest permissions:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.bignerdranch.andriod.gpslocalisation">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <!--
         The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
         Google Maps Android API v2, but you must specify either coarse or fine
         location permissions for the 'MyLocation' functionality. 
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

I have seen people use this and it work fine but when I open it on my phone i get the map loading up correctly but no current location.

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you.

Comment: where is your location manager code? xD

Comment: If you are testing this on 6.0+ you need to add permission request code. and If you are testing this on lower than 6 version you can see GPS icon on Map, just click on this icon to move camera to your current location

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get current location on start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35126928/get-current-location-on-start)

Comment: Thanks I released it was the permission that were the problem. However now the permissions pop up to allow my app access wont go away it just repeats forever until you deny permission.